How to transform a ReadableStream back into a file in TypeScript
right now I'm working on a Next.js Typescript project. I am using Primereact for my Frontend. I prepared a File Upload.


import { FileUpload } from 'primereact/fileupload';

<FileUpload mode="basic" name="demo[]" url="/api/upload" accept=".csv" auto maxFileSize={1000000} />



And wrote the API endpoint


// pages/api/upload/route.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const formData = await req.body;
            const reader = formData.getReader();
            const decoder = new TextDecoder();
            let csv = '';

            while (true) {
                const { done, value } = await reader.read();
                if (done) {
                    break;
                }
                const chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
                csv += chunk;
            }
            console.log('Received file upload:', csv);
            return Response.json(csv)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error handling file upload:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method Not Allowed' });
    }
}



This works just fine and when I upload a csv I get an output like this:
Received file upload: ------WebKitFormBoundaryug5eJHLPId2egEJm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="demo[]"; filename="Mappe1.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
Test1;1234
Test2;5678
------WebKitFormBoundaryug5eJHLPId2egEJm--
But how can I instead of decoding the ReadableStream transform the bytestream back into a csv? In this case I just want the csv to be saved in the same directory as the route.ts. In the future I will send the ReadableStream to a Java Backend but I would like to make it work here too.
It would be awesome if the solution also works if a word file is uploaded or a png for example!
Thanks for the help!
